# Why does copying to portaudio input buffer with memcpy is creating noise?

Tags: c++, portaudio

I'm just trying to copy the input buffer of portaudio in a callback function. Thats my callback:

```
static int recordCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                           void *userData )
{
   
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
    const SAMPLE *rptr = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    SAMPLE *wptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
    long framesToCalc;
    long i;
    int finished;
    unsigned long framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;
    memcpy(&circularBuffer[data->write], inputBuffer, 1024); // Assuming samplesPerFrame = FRAME_SIZE
    data->write = data->write + 1024;
    (void) outputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    if( framesLeft < framesPerBuffer )
    {
        framesToCalc = framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    }
    else
    {
        framesToCalc = framesPerBuffer;
        finished = paContinue;
    }
    data->frameIndex += framesToCalc;
    return finished;
}
```

And this is the original callback from portaudio examples:

```
static int recordCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                               unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                               const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                               PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                               void *userData )
    {
     
        paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
        const SAMPLE *rptr = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
        SAMPLE *wptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
        long framesToCalc;
        long i;
        int finished;
        unsigned long framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;
    
        (void) outputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
        (void) timeInfo;
        (void) statusFlags;
        (void) userData;
    
        if( framesLeft < framesPerBuffer )
        {
            framesToCalc = framesLeft;
            finished = paComplete;
        }
        else
        {
            framesToCalc = framesPerBuffer;
            finished = paContinue;
        }
    
        if( inputBuffer == NULL )
        {
            for( i=0; i<framesToCalc; i++ )
            {
                *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* left */
                if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* right */
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for( i=0; i<framesToCalc; i++ )
            {
                *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* left */
                if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* right */
            }
        }
        data->frameIndex += framesToCalc;
       

 return finished;
}
```

And I'm just using `memcpy` instead of to iterate pointer. But the sound I record has so much noise. I can't figure out the problem. Maybe, I'm missing the channels(2 channels) but I'm not sure. Do you have any idea?

You can access the full code from [here](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is true but I couldn`t specify the frame size correctly

Instead of this:

```
memcpy(&circularBuffer[data->write], inputBuffer, 1024); // 1024 = FRAME_SIZE
```

This will be better:

```
memcpy(&circularBuffer[data->write], inputBuffer, 1024*sizeof(float)); // Assuming 1024 = FRAME_SIZE
```

because of:

`typedef float SAMPLE;` is 4 bytes.

Comment: To not have yet another "magic" number in your code, make it `1024 * sizeof(float)` instead.